# Using Bash as eclipse external tools with node.js in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, eclipse, bash, ubuntu

OS = Ubuntu 14.04
I've been trying to add node.js as eclipse external tools after reading this [article](https://z0ltan.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/configuring-eclipse-to-run-standalone-javascript-files-using-node-jsgoogle-v8-engine/) which is based on Windows. So i am trying to apply it to Ubuntu 14.04 using bash shell, and it keeps giving me an error.

Here is the image of my setting.

[image]

And when i run JavaScript code with that, i get this error message on my eclipse console

`/bin/bash: eval: No such file or directory`

But when i tried with emulating terminal(both with eval and without eval), it execute JS code well.

demo1.js just have one line of code `console.log("TEST");` and i get these results.

```
owner@pcowner:~/workspace/javascriptDemo$ nodejs demo1.js
TEST
owner@pcowner:~/workspace/javascriptDemo$ eval nodejs demo1.js
TEST
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal run `which nodejs` and note the path (i.e. /usr/bin/nodejs). Back in your External Tools Configuration in Eclipse, enter that path for **Location**.

**Working Directory** remains `${project_loc}`

**Arguments** can be `${resource_name}` or `demo1.js`